# Cross compilation is failing for V8 7.4.288.22 version libraries in android project

Tags: android, cross-compiling, v8

I am trying to integrate the v8 libraries into android project and the compilation fails with below build error.

> hello-jni.cpp:42: error: undefined reference to
>   'v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport,
>   v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping,
>   std::__ndk1::unique_ptr >)'
>   ../../buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include/memory:3586: error:
>   undefined reference to
>   'std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_weak()'

I have built V8 libraries with below arguments.

> is_debug = false target_cpu = "arm" v8_target_cpu = "arm" target_os = "android" is_component_build = false v8_static_library = true v8_use_snapshot = true v8_use_external_startup_data = false icu_use_data_file = false

I Have tried several solutions suggested in google like below and nothing resolves the issue.

setting is_clang: false & use_custom_libcxx: false

Shared the sample project at below link.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=19qlaFauxhic193l1E0bTeh1SPo90rVge

Please help me in resolving the build issue.

Answer (score 0):

> undefined reference to 'v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport, v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping, std::__ndk1::unique_ptr >)'

Make sure you're linking against `libplatform.a`, which is part of V8's build output.

> undefined reference to 'std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_weak()'

That one should be addressed by `use_custom_libcxx = false`.